# How to I access the flashlight of my device?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flashlight

I've been trying to access the flashlight and other sensors using Flutter on my device. However, for the time being, I need the access to the flashlight only (just for the turn-on ad turn-off event), but the packages available on pub.dev are not null-safe due to which the compiler is throwing errors while using those packages. Is there a way to access the flashlight directly without using a package?

Ps. I have come across some answers that suggested the use of MethodChannel() but I couldn't understand how to implement them for my use.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/torch_controller/versions/0.3.0-nullsafety.1 ?